# Is there a point to doing 'import type' rather than 'import' with Flow?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, flowtype, commonjs

Flow allows you to use the following syntax to import types:

```
// SomeClass.js
export default class SomeClass {}

// SomeFile.js
import type SomeClass from './SomeClass';
```

What's the benefit of using `import type` instead of `import`? Does it tell Flow more information and let it perform better static analysis?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

For the specific case of classes, it is either example will work. The key thing is that it breaks down like this:

- `import type ... from` imports a Flow type
- `import ... from` imports a standard JS value, and the type of that value.

A JS class produces a value, but Flowtype also interprets a class declaration as a type declaration, so it is *both*.

So where is `import type` important?

1. If the thing you're importing doesn't have a value, using a value import will in some cases be interpreted as an error, because most JS tooling doesn't know that Flow exists.

- `export type Foo = { prop: number };` for instance can only be imported with `import type { Foo } from ...`, since there is no *value* named `Foo`

2. If the thing you're importing has a JS value, but all you want is the type

- Importing only the type can make code more readable, because it is clear from the imports that only the type is used, so nothing in the file could for instance, create a new instance of that class.
- Sometimes importing only the type will allow you to avoid dependency cycles in your files. Depending on how code is written, it can sometimes matter what order things are imported in. Since `import type ...` only influences typechecking, and not runtime behavior, you can import a type without actually requiring the imported file to execute, avoiding potential cycles.

Comment: "to avoid dependency cycles in your files / to avoid circular import errors" is also [mentioned](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-import-type-from-another-file) while using typescript

Answer (score 5):

As stated at this [link](https://flow.org/blog/2015/02/18/Import-Types/)

> With import type, you want to import the type of the class and not really the class itself.

An example given at the same link as below

```
// @flow

// Post-transformation lint error: Unused variable 'URI'
import URI from "URI";

// But if you delete the require you get a Flow error:
// identifier URI - Unknown global name
module.exports = function(x: URI): URI {
  return x;
}
```

Due to we imported `URI` into this component, `linter` will check if we have used the class in this component. However, we only using it as a flow type checking and hence `linter` will throwing an error saying we imported unused variable.