# What does `import type {Node} from 'react';` and usage in App: () => Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, import

Running this command:

```
npx react-native init AwesomeProject
```

In the `App.js` file I don't understand 2 lines:

```
import React from 'react';
import type {Node} from 'react';  // 1
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  ScrollView,
 // ..... Code .... 

const App: () => Node = () => {  // 2
   // ..... Code .... 


export default App;
```

1. Importing type Node

   Following [Is there a point to doing 'import type' rather than 'import' with Flow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50441093/is-there-a-point-to-doing-import-type-rather-than-import-with-flow), I understand that such import is used to import a *type* of object, for instance:

   ```
   import type { Array, Object, ... } from 'wherever';
   ```

   To be honest I am more concerned on the next point (probably If I understand that I would automatically get the this as well).
2. `const App: () => Node = () =>`

   All that I see is that App is a *variable* which references a function that returns an Object of type `Node` which this `Object` s also a function. Does it wrap the App into a 'React' instance or something?

Comment: `() => Node` is the _type_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What does `const App: () => Node = () =>` do and why you would want to use it?

If we remove the types, the code is:

```
const App = () => {
  // ... code
}
```

This is a react functional component.

Then on top of that is added a type: `() => Node`. This means it's a function that takes no parameters and returns a react `Node`. Types help with development by letting the computer analyze the code better, and point out bugs sooner (before even running the code)

Comment: Also, is there a documentation or Source code from where this Node come from?  Because Node is quite used in different topic in programming, I couldnt find anythin specific to React

Comment: `ok , so is not mandatory yes?` Correct, you are not required to use flow (or typescript) if you don't want to. `is there a documentation or Source code from where this Node come from` Your editor will probably let you click through to view the type definitions for React Nodes. But it's just a type describing what things can be returned by components. So JSX Elements (eg, `<div/>`), null, booleans, numbers, strings, or arrays of those things.

Comment: https://flow.org/en/docs/react/types/#toc-react-node